# Equation of a line with minimum and maximum constants.

Tags: linear-algebra

software engineer here, go easy.

I am writing a microcontroller to control the speed of a fan according to temperature.

My needs are:
- below 35 degrees fan must be off
- at 35 degrees, fan must start at 20%
- at 70 degrees and above, fan must be at 70%
- in between it is a linear function

With the coordinates (35, 20) and (70, 70) I am able to calculate the function of the line:

speed = 1.428 * temp - 30

But the problem is when temp is < 35 or temp > 70. I have to write some code to take those exceptions into account.

I am just wondering if I can have one formula in one go.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what functions you have available.

What you want is $$\text{speed} = I[\text{temp} \ge 35] \times (1.428 \times \min(\text{temp},70) - 30)$$

where $I[\,]$ is an indicator function taking the value $1$ when the statement is true and $0$ otherwise

Comment: I think it must be min instead of max

Comment: @ReinhardMeier - indeed.  Thank you

Comment: Clever, that will do! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you do (unless you tabulate), handling the "exceptions" will cost you at worse two comparisons. I see little reason to try and avoid them.

A nano-optimization is possible when the temperature has good chances of being in range:

```
T-= 35;
if (unsigned(T) <= 35)
    S= 1.428 * T + 20;
else
    S= T < 0 ? 0 : 70;
```

This can spare one comparison.